# Redirect a post request to vue application using nginx

Tags: vue.js, http, nginx, post, webserver

the auth workflow we currently are using sends a post request to a specified url (our vue application) after authentication is complete. Since it's a SPA it can't receive this post request and a 405 method not allowed error is shown on the browser.

I'm currently able to get around this locally by adding something like this into my `vue.config.js` file:

```
  devServer: {
    before: function(app) {
      app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    },
  }
```

But how would I configure something similar using nginx once it's actually deployed on a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone coming to this in the future, add the following line to nginx.conf

```
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```